# Sending List Controller To View

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller, view, controller

What is the best way sending List from controller to view. 
By the way i am new at MVC.
I want to send my companyList (at post controller) to view. 
If you ask why i want to show companyList[0].Name in the view and i want to do this operation under the "success" status in my ajax.

Thanks.

That is my controller code For Get

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    KargoDB database = new KargoDB();
    var query = database.States.Select(s => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = s.State_id.ToString(),
        Text = s.Description,
        Selected = s.State_id.Equals(1)

    });

    var model = new State()
    {
        lstStates = query.AsEnumerable()
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

That is my Controller Code For Post

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string senderAddress, string senderState, string receiverAddress, string receiverState,
    string receiverName, string receiverPhoneNumber, string requestDate, string cargoHeight, string cargoLenght,
    string cargoQuantity, string paymentType, string cargoWidth, string cargoWeight)
{

    RouteDetailRepository rdr = new RouteDetailRepository();
    int routeId = rdr.getRouteId(senderState, receiverState);
    List<RoutesDetail> companyList = rdr.getRouteDetail(routeId);
    if (companyList == null)
    {
        return JavaScript("Seçilen Güzergaha Sistemde Kayıtlı Olan Hiç Bir Kargo Firması Servis Yapmamaktadır.");
    }
    return Json(new { status = "success" });
}
```

as you can see i am returning success for my ajax.

That is part of my View Code

```
@model denemee.Models.State
 <script type="text/javascript">    
        $(document).on("click", "#btnSearch", function () {

            var senderAddress = document.getElementById("senderAddress").value;
            var senderState = document.getElementById("senderState").value;
            var receiverAddress = document.getElementById("receiverAddress").value;
            var receiverState = document.getElementById("receiverState").value;
            var receiverName = document.getElementById("receiverName").value;
            var receiverPhoneNumber = document.getElementById("receiverPhoneNumber").value;
            var requestDate = document.getElementById("datepicker").value;
            var cargoHeight = document.getElementById("cargoHeight").value;
            var cargoLenght = document.getElementById("cargoLength").value;
            var cargoQuantity = document.getElementById("cargoQuantity").value;
            var paymentType = document.getElementById("paymentType").value;
            var cargoWidth = document.getElementById("cargoWidth").value;
            var cargoWeight = document.getElementById("cargoWeight").value;


            if (senderAddress === "" || senderState === "" || receiverAddress === "" || receiverState === "" ||
                receiverName === "" || receiverPhoneNumber === "" || requestDate === "" || cargoHeight === "" ||
                cargoLenght === "" || cargoQuantity === "" || paymentType === "" || cargoWidth === "" ||
                cargoWeight === "") {
                alert("Lütfen Tüm Alanları Doldurunuz.")
            } else {    
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/Main/Index',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        'senderAddress' :  senderAddress,
                        'senderState': senderState,
                        'receiverAddress' :  receiverAddress,
                        'receiverState' :  receiverState,
                        'receiverName' :  receiverName,
                        'receiverPhoneNumber' :receiverPhoneNumber,
                        'requestDate': requestDate,
                        'cargoHeight': cargoHeight,
                        'cargoLenght' : cargoLenght,
                        'cargoQuantity' : cargoQuantity,
                        'paymentType' : paymentType,
                        'cargoWidth' : cargoWidth,
                        'cargoWeight' : cargoWeight,

                    },
                    success: function (msg) {

                    },
                    error: function (msg) {
                        alert(msg.responseText);
                    }        
                });
            }
        });    
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a property in your anonymous object using the value of companyList, like that:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string senderAddress, string senderState, string receiverAddress, string receiverState,
    string receiverName, string receiverPhoneNumber, string requestDate, string cargoHeight, string cargoLenght,
    string cargoQuantity, string paymentType, string cargoWidth, string cargoWeight)
{

    RouteDetailRepository rdr = new RouteDetailRepository();
    int routeId = rdr.getRouteId(senderState, receiverState);
    List<RoutesDetail> companyList = rdr.getRouteDetail(routeId);
    if (companyList == null)
    {
        return JavaScript("Seçilen Güzergaha Sistemde Kayıtlı Olan Hiç Bir Kargo Firması Servis Yapmamaktadır.");
    }
    return Json(new { status = "success", data = companyList });
}
```

And then in your javascript you can access companyList in success callback. The msg parameter from function is your JSON that contains the status and data property.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Main/Index',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        'senderAddress' :  senderAddress,
        'senderState': senderState,
        'receiverAddress' :  receiverAddress,
        'receiverState' :  receiverState,
        'receiverName' :  receiverName,
        'receiverPhoneNumber' :receiverPhoneNumber,
        'requestDate': requestDate,
        'cargoHeight': cargoHeight,
        'cargoLenght' : cargoLenght,
        'cargoQuantity' : cargoQuantity,
        'paymentType' : paymentType,
        'cargoWidth' : cargoWidth,
        'cargoWeight' : cargoWeight,

    },
    success: function (msg) {
        if(msg.status === "success") {
            //msg.data is your companyList
            //do whataver you need
        }
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        alert(msg.responseText);
    }        
});
```

You could also use jQuery to get value from inputs, instead using `document.getElementById`:

```
var senderAddress = $("senderAddress").val();
var senderState = $("senderState").val();
var receiverAddress = $("receiverAddress").val();
var receiverState = $("receiverState").val();
var receiverName = $("receiverName").val();
var receiverPhoneNumber = $("receiverPhoneNumber").val();
var requestDate = $("datepicker").val();
var cargoHeight = $("cargoHeight").val();
var cargoLenght = $("cargoLength").val();
var cargoQuantity = $("cargoQuantity").val();
var paymentType = $("paymentType").val();
var cargoWidth = $("cargoWidth").val();
var cargoWeight = $("cargoWeight").val();
```

Also you could use model binding feature from ASP.NET MVC, and create a classe that represent the view model of your page and use that instead receiver many parameters in Index action, look below:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string SenderAddress { get; set; }
    public string SenderState { get; set; }
    public string ReceiverAddress { get; set; }
    public string ReceiverState { get; set; }
    public string ReceiverName { get; set; }
    public string ReceiverPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string RequestDate { get; set; }
    public string CargoHeight { get; set; }
    public string CargoLenght { get; set; }
    public string CargoQuantity { get; set; }
    public string PaymentType { get; set; }
    public string CargoWidth { get; set; }
    public string CargoWeight { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ViewModel viewModel)
{
    RouteDetailRepository rdr = new RouteDetailRepository();
    int routeId = rdr.getRouteId(viewModel.SenderState, viewModel.ReceiverState);
    List<RoutesDetail> companyList = rdr.getRouteDetail(routeId);
    if (companyList == null)
    {
        return JavaScript("Seçilen Güzergaha Sistemde Kayıtlı Olan Hiç Bir Kargo Firması Servis Yapmamaktadır.");
    }
    return Json(new { status = "success" });
}
```

If you do that, you must change the name of fields in your javascript code, making them uppercase, like that:

```
data: {
    'SenderAddress' :  senderAddress,
    'SenderState': senderState,
    'ReceiverAddress' :  receiverAddress,
    'ReceiverState' :  receiverState,
    'ReceiverName' :  receiverName,
    'ReceiverPhoneNumber' :receiverPhoneNumber,
    'RequestDate': requestDate,
    'CargoHeight': cargoHeight,
    'CargoLenght' : cargoLenght,
    'CargoQuantity' : cargoQuantity,
    'PaymentType' : paymentType,
    'CargoWidth' : cargoWidth,
    'CargoWeight' : cargoWeight    
},
```

Comment: Thank you so much @AlbertoMonteiro

Comment: @UfukDoğan Any time, I happy that was useful to you :D

Comment: @UfukDoğan I see that you can do some otimizations in your code, do you want me to do that in answer?

Comment: @AlbertoMonteior of course, that will be very good for me, if you want you can add me on facebook and we can talk about my code. my mail address is ufukdogan1993@hotmail.com for facebook, you can find me using that mail, thank you again.

Comment: @UfukDoğan I will add otimization in stackoverflow, so everyone can learn this things to!!!

Comment: @AlbertoMonteior by the way, how can i change my label text using msg.data[0].Price

Comment: You can add a css class to your label, then use jQuery `$(".cssClassOfLabel").text(msg.data[0].Price)` something like that.

Comment: @UfukDoğan I added the improvements in my answer, look it again!!

Comment: @AlbertoMonteior thanks :) i just want to ask you something :) i can't do foreach in the success at ajax, how can i do. I got list in msg.data and according to list i want to make dynamic div. Like if i have 2 results in my msg.data i want to create 2 div and these div has labels after that like using foreach i just want to write my lists elements there. How can i do that?

Comment: @UfukDoğan there is no `foreach` in javascript, you must use for.
`for(var i = 0; i < msg.data.length; i++) { /*code to create div here*/ }`